# How to reduce excess distance between a label and another label through tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an F1 drivers' application, which gathers API data. The application has designated labels for where specific API content needs to be placed.

[image: image of problem]

What's happening is that whenever I put anything beside a designated label through .grid, the distance between whatever I put and the label is too big. A perfect example of this is in the `bottom_left_frame`. I've tried different ways (i.e, sticky, padding), but no luck. One way that seems to work is .configure(), but I don't think it's a scalable solution, and I want to place my objects through .grid()

Here's the code. Would appreciate the help!

```
#import necessary modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests
import json

root = Tk()
root.title("F1 Desktop Application")
root.geometry("500x600")
root.configure(bg="white")

#NEED TO UNDERSTAND PRECEDENCE BETWEEN WIDTH, HEIGHT SETTING, VS SPANS. STICKY MAKES PERFECT SENSE
top_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 300, height = 125)
top_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
top_frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 75)
top_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 300)


header_label = Label(top_frame, text = "F1 2022 Drivers App", font = ("Arial bold",14), bg = "white")
header_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

entry= Entry(top_frame)
entry.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

#search_button = Button(top_frame, text = "search")
#search_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)




left_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 250, height = 225, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 2)
left_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = NW, padx = 10, pady = 15)
#left_frame.grid_propagate(False)
left_frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 100)
left_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 200)

#left_frame_content = LabelFrame(, width = 125, height = 70)
#left_frame_content.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)


basic_info = Label(left_frame, text = "Basic Info ", font = ("Arial bold",14))
basic_info.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

full_name = Label(left_frame, text = "Full Name :")
full_name.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

driver_code = Label(left_frame, text = "Driver Code : ")
driver_code.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

nationality = Label(left_frame, text = "Nationality : ")
nationality.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)





bottom_left_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 250, height = 225)
bottom_left_frame.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = N, padx = 10)
bottom_left_frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 25)
bottom_left_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 200)




F1_career = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "F1 Career ", font = ("Arial bold",14))
F1_career.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

wins = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "Wins :")
wins.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

wins.configure(text = "Wins :" + " 7")

poles = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "Poles :")
poles.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

test = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "test")
test.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

podiums = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "Podiums :")
podiums.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

drivers_championships = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "Championships :")
drivers_championships.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)





bottom_right_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 250, height = 225)
bottom_right_frame.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
bottom_left_frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 50)
bottom_left_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 150)





root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I set the `sticky` value to "nsew" and the padx to zero it reduces the space between that frame and the other frames. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. I'm not sure I was looking to reduce the space between frames. Rather, it was to reduce the distance between two separate labels within bottom_left_frame. In this case, it was "Poles" and "test". The gap is too much. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You’re setting the minimum size of the column to 200 pixels. Have you tried reducing or removing the minimum size?

Comment: Hi Bryan. Yep I have, but it's the same issue. Removing it just makes the initial frame super tiny, but it still grows once more widgets are inside the frame

grid_propogate also doesn't seem to do the trick